# Looking for a comic series which take place on a planet where nature is illegal and populated by clones

Tags: story-identification, clones

I remember reading this story about 3 or 4 years ago. There were part 1, 2 and maybe 3 available at my local library.

I remember that, on this planet the reproduction was done by cloning and they were all programme to die at a certain age. I remember it was very cruel and not at all equal.

The only best example I remember is like the people enforcing the law *the policemen* lived for 400 days.

The medium class of people, *the workers and employees* lived for 40 years.

The highest class of society, *the leaders* lived for 400 years

and the queen lived for 4000 years.

There was a *Birthday* day where everyone that was their time to die in *the workers and employees* class (wich was the bigest class of individuals) had to go into a big canal in the center of the city and wait for the moment of their death. At this exact moment all the heads of these people simply exploded all at the same time. I remember seing an image of the canal filled with blood and body parts. 
While awaiting their death these people acted in different ways:

Some were scared to hell and tried to flee but were stoped by *the policemen*.

Some were partying like it was a normal thing (and it was).

Some were even making love in the canal as their last moment of life.

The nature was completely illegal, This big city was surronded by a little vegetation left on the planet and this place was the "sanctuary" of *the Rebels*, a group of people determine to bring equality and nature back.

I will take any hint please I've got to read this story back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is "[Megalex](http://avaxhm.com/comics/megalex_1_-_3.html)" by Alejandro Jodorowski with artwork by Fred Beltran.

[image]

This [Amazon review](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Megalex-Alexandro-Jodorowsky/dp/1594651337) details the cloning system:

> 'Megalex' introduces a sterile world whose surface has been almost
>   entirely covered in the rigidly engineered, technologically advanced,
>   and viciously authoritarian global-city-state for which the book is
>   named. With organic procreation banned, the genetically engineered
>   population is divided into classes, the upper class allowed 400 years
>   of life, while the lowest classes are only given 400 days.

Comment: yessssssssssssssssss that is exactly it !! Thanks a lot @Richard

Comment: http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i/i-m-awesome-true-story.png